# Google compute engine VM serial console access

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is it possible to get serial console access to a VM instantiated on Google compute engine? I see an option to view serial console output, however I would like to access the console in case VM cannot be reached via SSH

Comment: This question should be asked over at http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/google-compute-engine since it is not programming related.

Answer (score 2):

You can only see the serial output for now.

If you ever mess up your VM and you can't access the machine anymore you would create a second VM and attach the drives of your first VM to the second and chroot into the drives of your first VM.

Answer (score 1):

[Beta test of interactive serial port is available:](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console?hl=en_US&_ga=1.148185905.744733273.1468860841)

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata [INSTANCE_NAME]  \
    --metadata=serial-port-enable=1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this document: [interacting with serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console)
You can enable login from serial port on web console or by command.

[image: Enable connecting to serial ports]

### Command line

Enable serial console login

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata INSTANCE --metadata serial-port-enable=1
```

Login from  serial console

```
gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port [INSTANCE_NAME]
```